# "Object was not of the specified subclass [com.app.sportapp.entity.User] : Discriminator: player; - Hibernate, SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to get all users from my database. I am using `Postgresql`, `Hibernate` and `SpringBoot`.

Not only that, but I have a table `User` that is in association with table `Sport` and `Team` table.

**User.java**

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "User_Type")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;   
    private String lastName;    
    private String username;    
    private String email;    
    private String password;   
    private String contactNumber;

}
```

**Player.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Players")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="player", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Player extends User {

    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String notes;

}
```

**Coach.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Coaches")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="coach", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Coach extends User{

}
```

When I am trying to test my app to get all users from database with Postman I am getting following error:

`"Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.app.sportapp.entity.User] : Discriminator: player; nested exception is org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [com.app.sportapp.entity.User] : Discriminator: player"`

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. You have re-defined the `@DiscriminitorColumn` whereas you should only add `@DiscriminatorValue` for the types. I doubt that for a player the column suddenly changes from `user_type` to `player`. But I would expect the `user_type` column to hold the value `player`. You mapped the first, while you probably ment the second. Also your `User` should be abstract and and a `@MappedSuperclass` unless your `User` is also some type of user.

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me. I had a wrong mapping. Can you please write it as answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your mapping, you are overriding/redefining the [`@DiscriminatorColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html). You should use [`@DiscriminatorValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html) instead.

The `@DiscriminatorColumn` defines which column contains the value to use for mapping the row to the proper entity class. With `@DiscriminatorValue` you specify which value maps to which class.

Your code should look something like this.

```java
@Entity(name = "Players")
@DiscriminatorValue("player")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Player extends User {

    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String notes;

}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "Coaches")
@DiscriminatorValue("coach")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class Coach extends User{

}
```

Additionally, you might want to make your user `abstract` and add `@MappedSuperclass` to it as well.

```java
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "User_Type")
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class User { ... }
```

Unless there are also users that aren't players or coaches in your system (but then you would need an additional `@DiscriminatorValue` for that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer it helped a lot!